# How to override child's text alignment used in parent's column with crossAxisAlignment center?

Tags: flutter

How to override text alignment which is placed in column with crossAxisAlignment center?

```
Column(
    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
    children: [
      Text('Version: 1.0'), // this aligned in center
      SizedBox(height: 20),
      Text(
        'Сайт приложения', 
        style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline6,
        textAlign: TextAlign.left, // this does not align
      ),
    ],
)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try with align

```
Align(
alignment: Alignment.centerRight,
child: Text(
        'Сайт приложения', 
        style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline6,
        textAlign: TextAlign.left, // this does not align
      ),
)
```

Output:

[image]